# Loop through array of objects in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array`($rootScope.language);` of objects that look like this:

```
[{name: "Oskar", lastname: "Doe"},{name: "John", lastname: "Steward"}]
```

I want to loop through all of them in my template. I tried this:

```
    <div ng-repeat="entry in language"> 
       <p>{{name}} {{lastname}}</p>
    </div>
```

This outputs nothing and I don't get any errors. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you need to use $rootScope? Generally you don't want to put things there since it can be used like a global variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `name` or `lastname` directly on the scope, so you have to refer every `ng-repeat` item by an alias - in your case `entry`

That's why you have to use

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in language"> 
   <p>{{entry.name}} {{entry.lastname}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add entry to the variables like this:

```
{{entry.name}}
```